# Is it OK to edit an answer by another person to avoid it being mistaken for spam?

Tags: discussion, edits, link-only-answers, spam, self-promotion

I came across this answer today:

> [Unit tests for Javacc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5533357/303810)

The original answer was basically a link-only answer by the book author to the sample code freely available on the book's website.

This answer was a very helpful hint for me, but from the SO guidelines PoV this may be considered as self-promotion, link-only and spam - despite the clarification in the comments.

I wanted to avoid this so I have edited the original answer, making it more obvious that the user *is* the book author and that the code is available for free. I have also posted a minimal sample code.

Now I'm not quite sure if this is OK. The answer is now X times larger than the original answer (using the material by the same author).

Is it fine or did I go too far with my [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5533357/revisions)?

Comment: IMO, perfectly valid edit.

Comment: Way to go. This is what community is about. Nice one.

Comment: No problems with your edit but it is questionable if these Google query type questions should even be answered. My query on a few keywords found an example on the first page in Google...
But maybe I am too much of a hardliner.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I'd say that's perfectly reasonable (provided you're sure about the license terms, since you're effectively posting it as Creative Commons) and a very helpful way to resolve a poor answer.

I sometimes wish more users would fix problematic posts rather than instantly resort to a moderator bat signal to delete because community actions/edits scale compared to moderator actions and everybody wins.

Comment: Good point on licensing, I'll check that.

Comment: I did not manage to find out about the license so I've replaced the code with an analogous simple example.

Answer (score 22):

Yes, it is fine to edit. As Flexo has [mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277100/1906307), make sure the license on the code allows it.

However, I would suggest an additional action when you perform such edit: add a comment for the author that in its initial form the post could have been taken as spam. When I've left such comments, I've usually received a positive response. (I see you did leave a comment, but I mention it for future readers of this question and its answers.)